# SQL table not generating

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

I am trying to create a table and there seems to be an issue with the schema. Please the code below, everything runs fins until the FOREIGN KEY. If I comment out the FOREIGN KEY, it creates the table but with the foreign key I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'Products'.

Here is my Products schema

```
public void CreateProductTable()
{
    try
    {
        string tableName = "Products";
        string schema = "ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        "ProductName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , " +
                        "ProductType VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , " +
                        "ProductNumber int NOT NULL , " +
                        "ProductCondition VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , " +
                        "ProductActiveInactive TINYINT NOT NULL , " +
                        "OnLoan BIT NOT NULL " +
                        "FOREIGN KEY(BrandID) REFERENCES ProductBrands(BrandID)";
        Helper.CreateTable(tableName, schema);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log errors
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

And here is my BrandProducts schema:

```
public void CreateProductBrandTable()
{
    try
    {
        string tableName = "ProductBrands";
        string schema = "BrandID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        "BrandName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL";
        Helper.CreateTable(tableName, schema);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log errors
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Helper.CreateTable

```
public static void CreateTable(string tableName, string tableStructure)
{
    string sql = $"CREATE TABLE {tableName} ({tableStructure})";
    using (var connection = GetConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Execute(sql);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

GetConnection:

```
public static bool DoTablesExist()
{
    var connection = GetConnection();
    string sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {connection.Database}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" +
                 $" WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'";
    using (connection)
    {
        int number = connection.QuerySingle<int>(sql);
        if (number > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you let us know what helper.Create Table is doing...it is difficult to suggest solution as the table creation is done by other library.

Comment: @AmitVerma post update. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: You are missing comma after `OnLoad BIT NOT NULL`

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Here I can see Brand should be created first as Product is dependent on Brand. Are you doing in same way? First  creation of brand table then creation of product table.

Comment: Yes the product brand table is created before the products table. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: It might be helpful if you showed the code where you called the table creation functions.  It's hard to see how you would get `'Invalid object name 'Products'` because, presumably, there's an error when creating `Products` and you're not showing that `Console.WriteLine()` output.

Comment: Might be being blind, but I can't see any column in products called BrandId that will equate to ProductBrands.BrandId?

Comment: Multiline strings in code are a lot easier to read if you make it a single  `@"string with newlines"`. I know VS stops the string and starts it again for you if you press return, but it sure turns into a bit of a mess of `"+"`. Making it a verbatim string neatens that up

Comment: As another aside, using EF code first would make your life massively easier overall, and you can get it to create a database from your C# classes' properties

Comment: @CaiusJard that was the case. I didn't have a BrandID but now I am getting this error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Products__BrandI__286302EC". The conflict occurred in database "Tool_Tracker", table "dbo.ProductBrands", column 'BrandID'.

Comment: You are inserting a product without first having inserted a matching brand. Must insert into primary key end first

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server please only tag the relevant RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `BrandId` column in products table in order to be able to cite it as an FK. While it would be lovely to be able to simply write `FOREIGN KEY(x) REFERENCES(y)` and sql server would create a column X  of the same type and size as Y, it doesn't work - the column list to create needs X in it/X needs to exist first

Remember to insert your related Brand records before you try to insert your Products; a brand has to exist first so product can reference it